# OnDragListener - is there some compatibility library for Android levels < 11?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have an app that uses `OnDragListener`.

Since this has been introduced only in API Level 11, I am looking for a library (similar to ActionBarSherlock for Fragments) that supports this functionality for lower levels.

Is there anything like this available that could help to make the app compatible with lower than Android 11 versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...the easiest solution I found was to implement a double sided connection logic. So press on the destination and then select the target and vice versa - I could even use lots of the dragging code, just not the dragging itself...